# How could fix list_display columns width in admin model

Tags: python, django

I have normal admin.py with custom list_display, list_filter and search_fields but the issue is some of columns looks so ugly, how could I arrange it to be fixed width or by max-width and save people eyes ?

img of ugly admin.py : [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y9EH.png)

```
class FollowUpsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'company', 'contact_person', 'action', 'result', 'next_action', 'new_action_date', 'result_class', 'notes', 'is_active', 'updated_date', 'created_date')
    list_filter = ('user', 'company', 'result_class',  'is_active')
    search_fields = ('user__email', 'company__name', 'action', 'result', 'next_action', 'new_action_date', 'result_class', 'notes', 'is_active', 'created_date')

admin.site.register(FollowUp, FollowUpAdmin)
```

Comment: It seems normal to me. Which column and what change do you want to apply?

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar "Result" & "Note" so small, "Next Action" bigger, "Company" is more bigger